# Android Alarm Manager Backgroud Service Class Not Showing Data in Textview

Tags: java, android, web-services, textview, alarmmanager

I am Using Alarm Manager for fetching data from Webservice Every 10 minutes.

here Calling the Service from Main activity Using Alarm manager.

My Problem:

Every 10 mins data fetching from Webservice working fine, but in service Class not able to add the Textview .

Help me how to Solve it.

Service Calling from Main activity Oncreate

```
Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyAlarmServiceforLocalDataSync.class);
    pendingintent3 = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 2,myIntent2, 2);
    AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar2.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingintent3);
    alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), 600 * 1000,pendingintent3);
```

Comment: How your getting the data from the service to Activity?

Comment: but iam using async task for getting data from webservice data showing in Service Class but i want send back to MainActivty class

Comment: use broadcast receivers to send the data to the Activity, but only for the limited size data. For heavy data user Binders.

Comment: any sample code snippet for Use binders?

Comment: have a look for the idea : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Local_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion.this code Looks some thing difficult.... :(